# Angular 8 multiple mat-checkbox required validation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

I have multiple dynamic mat-checkbox and i want to implement validation "at least one of them is selected".
Here is the html code:

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let data of pointsDepart; let i=index" [ngClass]="i == 1 ? 'marginTop': ''">
        <mat-checkbox color="primary" formControlName="pointDepart" ngDefaultControl>{{data}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

How can I implement my validator, please ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below link for the validation of check boxs and email id
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-at-least-one-checkbox-checked

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, so you recommend to not use angular material's `<mat-checkbox>` and use `<input type="checkbox">` instead ?

Comment: This response should be in the comment section of the original answer.